# flutter [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException Requests from this client app are blocked

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm building a flutter/firebase app and im getting the following error when I try to login to firebase with email: [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests from this Android client application com.google.firebase.are blocked. ] I've checked and I do have the proper google-services, all the gradle files are correct, all the necessary firebase packages are installed on their latest versions and  I have enabled the sign in method on firebase console and it has the same name on both ends, I still have no idea why this error is being raised.

```
StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return const FeedRoute();
    } else {
      return const LoginWidget();
    }
  },
));
```

and the function being called inside the LoginWidget:

```
Future<void> signIn() async {
  try {
    final UserCredential authResult =
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: emailController.text.trim(),
      password: passwordController.text.trim(),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }

  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/feed_route');
  }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using any SHA certificate fingerprints under your Firebase Project Settings?

Comment: It was being blocked from google cloud console just for android, somebody else made that mistake